# How to include Images and Tables in Textfields when exporting to PDF?

Tags: html, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

Is there a way to include images and tables in Textfields with markup=html, when exporting a PDF using JasperReports?

When I add a textfield with markup=html to my report, basic HTML support is provided out of the box, e.g.:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement .../>
    <textElement markup="html"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<html>some <b>bold</b> text</html>"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

However, more complex HTML seems not to be supported. If I got that right, one would have to write a custom MarkupProcessor to transform the incoming HTML to jrxml and plug it into the JasperReports engine to handle more complex examples.

Since we use a [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) to handle the input, the list of used tags should be manageable. Secondly, we already use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse and cleanup HTML, which might be useful implementing the MarkupProcessor.

Is there an example I could build on? As I said, I'm mainly looking for image (`img`) and table (`table`, `tr`, `td`) support.

If not, is there an alternative to achieve this using JasperReports?

Comment: I have the same question, did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks it doesn't seem to be possible, at least I haven't found an easy solution. What I ended up doeing, is using http://www.docx4java.org to generate .docx files containing the HTML. As it turns out, our users are quite happy getting Word files instead of PDF, so I'm good with that. It may however be possible, to convert the resulting docx to pdf, but I haven't tried yet. By the way, docx4j seems to use https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/ under the hood to import the HTML.

Comment: You can not insert the image in the text field. Here is my email id. please ping me your exact scenario. mabtestflight@gmail.com.

Answer (score 4):

It seems impossible indeed. What we do now instead is inserting images at predefined locations in the jrxml instead, and config limited functionality of ckeditor. Another option would be to extract the image urls from ckeditor and insert them at predefined locations in the jrxml, but we don't use that right now.